# NodeJS - code inside an async function executes out of order

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I have a werid problem. What i want to do is, when calling an api, i want to make a request to the postgresql db with a bulk insert. First, i execute the loop which reads a file and extracts data from it to form the values array. Then, i want to generate a bulk insert request with pg-promise library. But when the code executes, what i get is that it tries to generate a request before the loop even starts, and it throws an error about an empty array. What the?

```
async import(req, res) {
    var rd = readline.createInterface({
       input: fs.createReadStream('.../file.csv'),
       console: false
     });

    const createQuery = `INSERT INTO 
          table('columns') 
          VALUES ?`;
    const values = [];
    rd.on('line', function(line) {
       //stuff
         values.push({
           //stuff
         });
       }
     });
    const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['columns'], {table: 'table'});
    const query = pgp.helpers.insert(values, cs);
```

I've removed the details, but i hope this provides enough info. I've tried to put console logs before, in and after the loop, and first, the stuff before and after the loop gets logged, the error is thrown, and then the loop executes and logs stuff. Do i not understand or miss something?

Comment: You likely have to `await` any Promises inside your `async` function (that's what makes it async-await!)

Comment: There shouldn't be any promises in this part of the code as far as i'm aware, there are only two of them later on, which execute the queries. I thought about that before, tried putting await where it was possible, to no luck. And, afaik, async just means that such functions execute out of order, not what's inside them, wouldn't that be a mess if everything inside the async function would be out of sync too?
UP: it actually seems that that's what's going on lol. Pretty new to the async stuff in js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just making the function `async` doesn't accomplish anything for you here by itself.  You have to find out what asynchronous operations you can `await` in order to serialize your asynchronous operations.

In the latest versions of node.js, you can use the `for await ()` structure with the asynchronous iterator in the readline interface to process all the lines.

```
async import(req, res) {
    var rd = readline.createInterface({
       input: fs.createReadStream('.../file.csv'),
       console: false
     });

    const createQuery = `INSERT INTO 
          table('columns') 
          VALUES ?`;
    const values = [];
    for await (const line of rd) {
        values.push({...})
    }
    const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['columns'], {table: 'table'});
    const query = pgp.helpers.insert(values, cs);
}
```

FYI, you can see an example of this in the [readline doc](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_symbol_asynciterator).

---

You also don't need to use `async` at all as you can solve it by just putting your last two lines into an event listener for the `close` event:

```
import(req, res) {
    var rd = readline.createInterface({
       input: fs.createReadStream('.../file.csv'),
       console: false
     });

    const createQuery = `INSERT INTO 
          table('columns') 
          VALUES ?`;
    const values = [];
    rd.on('line', function(line) {
       //stuff
         values.push({
           //stuff
         });
       }
     }).on('close', () => {
        // done with all line processing here
        const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['columns'], {table: 'table'});
        const query = pgp.helpers.insert(values, cs);
    });
}
```

Comment: Didn't know about the for await thing, thanks. It actually worked. So, the code inside the async function also executes out of sync? I only knew that the async functions themselves would execute out of order. 

Also, this was just a part of the function, i actually do use functions for executing queries later on, which return promises, so, don't i have to use async for that?

Comment: @Noname - All `async` does here is allow you to use `await`.  Without using `await`, `async` doesn't change the sequencing of anything.

Comment: then why did i get the wrong order of execution in that part of the code? I really don't get that lol

Comment: @Noname - `rd.on('line', ...)` does not block.  It just registers an event handler for the `line` event and then the lines of code immediately after it (where you have your `pgp.xxx` code) execute before any of those `line` events have fired.  This is the standard, non-blocking, event driven nature of node.js asynchronous operations.  Making the function `async` didn't change that behavior at all until we added the `for await ()`.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `rd.on()` you are just establishing an event with a callback to be called when the line event occurs.  All your code is doing is establishling the callback but then proceeding with the rest of your code which then tries to insert the values in the database.  You need to move the code that inserts into the database inside the callback of your `rd.on()` after you loop through all your values and push them into the array.

However, I'm not familiar of what the line even is in the case of a file.  If it is truly line by line for the file then you obviously can't bulk insert there.  My suggestion at that point would be to move that step into its own asyn function and `await` the result of that function before doing the insert.